# UI blocking on sending another request in Child Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, fragment, loopj

I have been using loopj library to interact with my server.
I have created a view pager inside a fragment and thus created child fragments
In these child fragment when I send a request to the server I get correct response. 
The problem arises when I send the refresh request to the server ,the response is still correct but the UI becomes black tinted and I cannot interact with UI anymore.

Screen looks like this after first request:
[image: after first request]

And after second request the screen becomes
[image: after second request]

My Code for connecting with server is :

```
private void setWatchlistData() {


    String url = "";
    switch (watchlist_type) {
        case 1:
            url = "/getWatchList";
            break;
        case 2:
            url = "/getTrendingWatchList";
            break;
        case 3:
            url = "/getRecommendedWatchList";
            break;
    }

    responseHandler = new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
                if (swipeRefresh.isRefreshing())
                    swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    if (!response.isNull("status")) {
                        if (response.getBoolean("status")) {
                            assets = new ArrayList<Asset>();
                            JSONArray arr = response.getJSONArray("watchlist");
                            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                                Asset a = new Asset();
                                a.setType(new AssetType(obj.getJSONObject("type")));
                                a.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                a.setId(obj.getInt("id"));

                                switch (a.getType().getType()) {
                                    case AssetType.ASSET_TYPE_STOCK:
                                        a.setSymbol(obj.getString("symbol"));
                                        assets.add(a);
                                        break;
                                }

                            }
                            setData();
                        } else {
                            new SweetAlertDialog(getActivity(), SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE).setTitleText("Error").setContentText(response.getString("message")).setConfirmText("Ok").setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                                    sweetAlertDialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }).show();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            Log.d(TAG, responseString + "");
            progressDialog.dismissWithAnimation();
            new SweetAlertDialog(getActivity(), SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE).setTitleText("Error Occured").setContentText(responseString + "").show();
        }


    };

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.add("user_id", String.valueOf(new UserDetailsHandler(getActivity()).getUser().getId()));
    client.setTimeout(99999);
    client.cancelAllRequests(true);
    client.get(CommonUtils.BASE_URL + url, params, responseHandler);

    progressDialog.show();
}
```

Swipe Refresh function:

```
        swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            setWatchlistData();
        }
    });
```

After first call the watchlist gets updated, but on swipe refresh it shows the isssue.

Answer (score 0):

Your  setWatchlistData() method needs to be wrapped in a thread. Avoid networking in main thread!

Comment: loopj library already makes the call using the AsyncTask so doesn't it solves that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem it was not in the request but in the dialog library I was using. The problem was because I was showing dialog again without initialising it again.